# deepcopy fails on a subclass of deque

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
from collections import deque
import copy
class Foo(deque):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()

foo = Foo()
foo_copy = copy.deepcopy(foo)
```

Here, `deepcopy(foo)` fails with the following message:

`TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`

On the other hand, the exact same code with `Foo` inheriting from a `list` or a `dict` works just fine.  I can make the deepcopy call work by implementing my own `__deepcopy__` method in class Foo, but can someone point me to an explanation of what exactly is going on here? Why does `deepcopy()` fail on `Foo` that inherits from `deque` but doesn't fail when it inherits from other built-in classes?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the simplest approach that I would use would be supporting pass-through arguments to the parent constructor.

```
from collections import deque
import copy
class Foo(deque):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

foo = Foo()
foo_copy = copy.deepcopy(foo)
```

I'm not sure, though, if it will work properly with how you are customizing that class.

Comment: The code in OP is just a minimal example, and I was indeed specifying arguments when calling `super().__init__()`. So your example works, but it doesn't quite work for my needs. Also, what I'm after here is an explanation of what is happening; I already know how to make this work for me (by implementing `__deepcopy__()`).